# bright parts of normals turns blacks

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normal-map

( I'm on blender 2.81 and rendering in cycle ) 
I've problems with my normals. 
Everything is plugged right, but when I set my normal map and rendering my scene, all the most brightnen parts are black. I mean, the part of the normal which theoricaly receive the most light turns black, not just dark

As you can see on the pictures below, it happens when I have a short angle view, from top view there are less bugs.

I tried everything ( change light, change normal soft, invert RGB... ) nothing work. 
The only things that decrease this effect is to set normal strenght from 1 to 2 ( from 2 to 10 there is this black )

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm not too good at guessing, would you mind sharing the normal map image?